# Discord.py is there a way to split a command into multiple messages?

Tags: python, discord.py

For example, if a command had multiple arguments like:

```
@client.command()
async def command(ctx, channel, time, prize):
     //code
```

How do I make it so that it asks for a different argument in every message? Something like this:
Bot: What channel?
User: (channel name)
Bot: How long?
User: (time)
Bot: What's the prize?
User: (prize)

If it helps, I'm making a giveaway bot.

Answer (score 0):

Use [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for). You can even specify how long the bot should wait.

Example:

```py
@client.command()
async def some_command_name(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    try:
        await ctx.send("Channel?")
        channel = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
        await ctx.send("Time?")
        time    = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
        await ctx.send("Prize?")
        prize   = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        # do something
```